# Out of memory error on sonar build using jacoco with coverage per test activated

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, out-of-memory, code-coverage, jacoco

My jenkins Job always fails on "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" running the mvn sonar:sonar command.

The problem comes from the jacoco analysis. Coverage per test is activated and I realy need this information.

I've got a huge project : 
556 000 LOC.
8411 TESTS.
Jacoco dump file is more than 10Go...

I'm using : 
java 7
sonar-jacoco-listeners 3.8
jacoco-maven-plugin 0.7.5.201505241946
sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2

I'm looking for either : 
- finding the good way to increase memory parameters, 
for example: 
 -Xmx15g -XX:MaxPermSize=12g -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit in the MAVEN_OPTS of the sonar action in jenkins doesn't make it
- playing with jacoco configuration for having a smaller dump file without loosing any info

For information the command line jacoco:report (out of jenkins, sonar) takes 10 hours.

Comment: Anyway, I do confirm that this feature doesn't scale well.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I'll try to find a different way to generate jacoco dumps

Comment: I've tried to split my test executions into different jacoco dumps but the jacoco:merge command looses the coverage per test information

Answer (score 0):

Did you ensure that your underlying machine provides this amount (15 GB) of RAM ?

We ran into same error message, but don't have such a huge project. For us it was enough to run the **Standalone SonarQube Analysis** with JVM Options *-Xmx1024m* to get rid of this problem.

[image]